# Creating a Mono binary install package for CentOS 5.2

Tags: mono, centos

I'm new to Linux but have to port a asp.net app to Linux platform. (CentOS 5.2)

I downloaded the mono source files and manually build them on my dev box, because there's no aviable Binary package for CentOS 5.2 (almost the same as RedHat), the app works well on the dev box.

The next step is to setup the production server, which has minimal libraries installed.
My question is... how to make the Mono binary files into a install package so I don't need to download and build them in the production server.
(My dev box is the same configuration as the production one)

I have tried to copy all mono related files into the server, but with no luck... May I missed some files or some settings...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT:

Recently, Mono announced support for RHEL/CentOS.  You can get packages from them [here](http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/download-stable/RHEL_5/).

Answer (score 0):

You can still get binary RPMS [here](http://origin-download.mono-project.com/archive/2.10.2/download/RHEL_5/)